# Adding download button with different quality option in HTML video tag

Tags: html, download, html5-video

How could make it possible to have a download button with an option for choosing different download quality for an HTML5 video tag?
Is there any specific free open source library for it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: **(1)** Javascript is the free API you're looking for. I recommend NOT trying to edit each browser brand's own unique styling (_eg:_ too many `IF` statements).  **(2)** Define your meaning of _"download"_ here (_eg:_ is it _"Save a video file to device storage"_ or meaning _"select a different quality for playback inside the page"_...   Either you want a list (to select save quality)  or you want to disable `controls` in video tag and make your own user interface graphics like how Youtube and Vimeo had to do.

Comment: many thanks for your help